# Finding all records associated with User with a has_many through association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, collections, controller

I have the following relationships:

**user.rb**

```
has_many :ownerships
has_many :restaurants, :through => :ownerships
```

**restaurant.rb**

```
has_many :ownerships
has_many :users, :through => :ownerships
```

I also have a Menu model that `belongs_to :restaurant`.

So clearly, there is no direct link between a `menu` and a `user` unless you go through `restaurant`.

I'm trying to make it so that only Menu's that were created by the `user` are displayed.

I'm able to display only the restaurants created by the current logged in user by this method:

**restaurants_controller.rb**

```
class RestaurantsController < ApplicationController

  # GET /restaurants
  # GET /restaurants.json
  def index
    if current_user.has_role? :admin
      @restaurants = Restaurant.all
    elsif current_user.has_role? :user
      @restaurants = current_user.restaurants
    end
  end
```

**How can I do the same under my `menus` controller by going through `restaurant`?**

I've tried:

```
@menus = current_user.restaurants.menus
```

And

```
@menus = current_user.restaurants.each.menus
```

Amongst other things but nothing seems to work. I always get the `undefined method`menus' for nil:NilClass`, which I understand; I'm not getting to the`menus` properly.

I'm thinking of making a loop that goes through each `restaurant` and adds the `menu` attached to it but am not 100% sure how to do that within the `menu` controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add a new association to the `user` model like this:

```
class User
  has_many :menus, :through => :restaurants
```

When you perform a `current_user.menus`, it will automatically fetch all menus from the restaurants from the user you have. Hope it helps.